# How to search at vim 'scriptnames' command

Tags: vim

The vim 'scriptnames' command output all scripts loaded. The problem is that I can't find any practical way to filter/search/find on it. I want to look for some script without having to do this by "eye brute force".

Comment: I do not know it there is a pure vim way of doing this, but a workaround would be to run vim inside `tmux` and then use `tmux`'s search feature to search what you want. And if  you are inside a terminal emulator, then your use its search feature too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `script` command, there are only `scriptencoding` and `scriptnames` (which can be abbreviated as `scr`, according to `:h :scr`).  I presume you're looking for `scriptnames`.

With Vim 8 you can filter the results of most commands with `:filter`:

```
:filter /pattern/ scriptnames
```

(cf. `:h :filter`).

With older versions of Vim you can redirect all messages to a file before running `:scriptnames`, then cancel the redirection:

```
:redir >file
:scriptnames
:redir END
```

(cf. `:h :redir`).  Alternatively, you can redirect messages to a register, then paste the contents of the register to a buffer:

```
:redir @a
:scriptnames
:redir END
:new
"aP
```

Finally, Tim Pope's plugin [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) adds a command `:Scriptnames` that runs `:scriptnames` and loads the results into a quickfix list.

Comment: FYI `:scriptnames` can be shortened to `:script`.

Comment: @romainl As I said: it can be abbreviated to `:scr`.  On older versions of Vim that meant it could be also abbreviated to anything between `:scr` and `:scriptnames` (including `:script`), but that is discouraged these days.

Comment: So `:script` exists. Short names are discouraged in vimscripts because they make things hard to read without providing any benefit but they are more than encouraged on the command-line.

Comment: @romainl You miss the point. During a recent cleanup of command names before the release of Vim 8 it was discovered that a number of commands conflicted because of the implicit abbreviations. For this reason, only the shortest and the longest names should be used. In the good Vim tradition however the implicit names will probably still stay with us for ever and ever, in the name of backwards compatibility. They are still discouraged.

Comment: I was talking about scriptnames, sorry. I didn't even know about that full name. The answer just works!!!! Thanks!

PS: I edited the question replacing "script" by "scriptnames". Thanks for pointing that out too :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `:redir`, we have `execute()` with recent versions of vim.

Thus, you can play with `:echo filter(split(execute('scritnames'), "\n"), 'v:val =~ "somepattern")` or `:new`+`put=execute(':scriptnames')`+search in the buffer as you would have explored a log life.